# Username availability with AJAX doesn't return any results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Below is a very basic script to check a **username availability.**

**The gif loading icon appears** as soon as I type something but then, for some reasons, **nothing happens** whereas there should be either "OK" or "not available" showing up within #status.

HTML:

```
  <label>Username</label> 
    <input type="text" class="input" name="username" id="username"/>
    <span id="status"></span>
```

JS part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#username").change(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var msgbox = $("#status");

        if (username.length >= 4) {
            $("#status").html('<img src="images/gif/ajax-loading.gif">');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_check.php",
                data: "username=" + username,
                success: function(msg) {
                     $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {

                        if (msg === 'OK') {
                            msgbox.html('Available');
                         } else {
                             msgbox.html(msg);
                          }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {

                $("#status").html('Cannot be less than 3  letters');
         }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's ajax_check.php:

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $rows = query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

   if (count($rows) == 1) {
       echo 'not available!';
   } else  {
       echo 'OK'; 
            }
}
?>
```

I've checked the query, and it works fine.

Also, the **JS console doesn't report any error.**

Any ideas?

Comment: For one, in Javasrcipt, use if (msg === "OK") the triple === is very important to convert to in almost any comparison you make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $("#status').ajaxComplete line is unnecessary. If you are in success: function(msg) then it is complete. Remove the lines I highlight below with ->>

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "ajax_check.php",
     data: "username=" + username,
     success: function(msg) {
         ->> REMOVE THIS $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {

                    if (msg == 'OK') {
                        msgbox.html('Available');
                     } else {
                         msgbox.html(msg);
                      }
                });
            ->> AND THIS }
        });
```

Comment: +1. Indeed it didn't make any sense to have this line. It now works ! I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to.